# Implement outlook calendar api in outlook add-in

Tags: c#, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps, office365api

I'm trying to implement the Office365 Outlook Calendar API inside the Outlook 365 Add-in. The Outlook Calendar API is fully implemented in the web application. Everything works fine with OAuth2 and the returned auth_token in the web application.

I'm having issues to sign in with OAuth2 inside the add-in. If you open the OAuth2-Login by Microsoft inside the add-in, it opens a Internet Explorer instance once you entered your appdev****@outlook[dot]com-account. This does not work with the auth_token saved in the session.

I tried to save the auth_token in a database (see //Test part) and request it for the user inside the add-in. This errors with a **DataServiceClientException**: **Unauthorized**
*Unknown location.*

```
    [Route("SignIn")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";

        string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "outlook", null, HttpContext.Request.Scheme));

        Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(scopes, null, clientId,
            redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

        return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
    }

    [Route("Authorize")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        string authCode = Request.Query["code"];

        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";

        string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(Url.Action("Authorize", "outlook", null, HttpContext.Request.Scheme));

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        try
        {
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authCode, redirectUri, credential, scopes);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("access_token", authResult.Token);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("user_email", GetUserEmail(authContext, clientId));

            //*** TEST ***
            _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email == "appdev****@outlook.com").AccessToken = authResult.Token;
            _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email == "appdev****@outlook.com").Email = GetUserEmail(authContext, clientId);

            return Content("Access Token: " + authResult.Token + " Email: " + GetUserEmail(authContext, clientId));
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**
This is a common problem with Office add-in new generation (formerly App for Office) and OAUTH authentication. The fact that the add-in runs in a sandboxed iFrame force the authentication to be made in a popup window. There are also some problems to retrieve the auth token in the parent (sandboxed iFrame) window because frame communications are forbidden in this context.
I proposed a solution [here](http://benoitpatra.com/2015/05/28/implementing-the-oauth-2-0-flow-in-app-for-office-sandboxed-environment/) but the best solution comes from Richard DiZerega and is proposed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in.aspx).
From what I have understood, you try to save the auth_token in a database so it will be requested by the iFrame add-in later on. It is closed to what Richard DiZerega proposes.

**Old mistaken answer**
You are facing this issue because you probably registered you Azure AD app as a web application. Now you are requesting it with a native client without any 'url location' that is why this is failing.

There is a different authentication scenario for [native client](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#application-types-and-scenarios).

I think this is no big deal just [register another app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/) in your Azure AD for native client (this is the first question asked when you create an app).

Comment: I don't host either the web application nor the add-in on azure. I registered the add-in via: apps.dev.microsoft.com. Further I use angular in the frontend to use the advantages of a single-page application. I have recently read about the OpenID Connect to get the authorization key, instead of OAuth2. Is the OpenID Connect a better fit for my project?

Comment: 1 - Registering the app in azureAD is different from 'hosting' the app or add-in on azure. It is just for the authentication purpose and requesting Microsoft APIs (Office365/Graph API etc.), the web app could be hosted anywhere else and could be also a native client app. I did not know of apps.dev.microsoft.com  but it does not seems as powerful as AzureAD.

Comment: 2- I use OpenID connect for a code authorization flow where the server does the authenticated request to the Office365 APIs instead of the client itself (native client or SPA webapp). It is much more complicated but for my case I needed it. If you only need the client (instead of your server) to make the requests to the Outlook APIs, I suggest that you have a look adal.js or adal angular. Lots of sample here https://github.com/AzureAD

Comment: I read again your question and I see that I was completely mistaken. When you spoke about "add-in" I thought .NET client add-in.

Comment: Oh ok. It is an Outlook 365/Exchange addin. Just the XML-File and my hosted web application. For further information: The web application runs ASP.Net 5, MVC 6 and AngularJS.